# React & Axios - Get values from an object inside of an object

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am working on a little project here and I got stuck when I started working with the API.

So the issue I am having is that I need to get access to the "price" section in the api. Here is an example of one product in the api:
[image]

I've managed to get into the `0: Object` etc, so I have access to `name` & `brandName` etc. But I also need to get into the `price` thats in there.

Did some tries myself but non of it succeeded.

Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

const ApiTest = (props) => {
  const [product, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState([]);

  const getProducts = () => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
      params: {
        store: "US",
        offset: "0",
        categoryId: "4209",
        limit: "48",
        country: "US",
        sort: "freshness",
        currency: "USD",
        sizeSchema: "US",
        lang: "en-US",
      },
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        setProducts(response.data.products);
        console.log(response.data.products);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getProducts}>Get Products</button>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {product.map((post) => (
            <li key={post.id}>{post.brandName}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ApiTest;
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full response you get from the API?

Comment: Also, are you saying `post.price.currency` for example, is not working ?

Comment: @RonB. Posted on pastebin: `yP8nXTSc`

Comment: @NisanthReddy oh, it did work. Strange, I tried it on google chrome earlier but changed to Mozilla for designing the page. And it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

`products[0].price.currency`

Comment: A strange take on the classic Beatles song, but correct