# Can you render an object inside an object?

Tags: reactjs, express, object, axios, render

I'm not sure how I would select this data if it's possible: [Console Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz9oD.png), I am trying to select the data within the 'posts' table, since I have relations setup for the users table & posts table

This is how I usually render the data.

```
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.postData);
        if (this.state.postData.length === 0) {
            return <div>Profile data not found</div>
        }

        const dashPost = this.state.postData.map(post => (
            <div key={post.UserId}>
                <h1>{post.FirstName}</h1>
            </div>
        ));

        // Jquery animations can go here

        return <div>{dashPost}</div>
    }
```

I am wondering if it's possible to render the post data that comes with the user.

I decided to give this a try, but I figured it wouldn't work.

```
{post.posts.PostTitle}
```

I've came across this forum: [React & Axios - Get values from an object inside of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609768/react-axios-get-values-from-an-object-inside-of-an-object)

BUT I have no idea how to actually implement it.

Comment: Looking at the naming `post.posts` you might have multiple posts in array, have you tried to `console.log` out the content of `post.posts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at **this.state.postData** from image, **post.posts** is an Array. Try **{post.posts[0].PostTitle}** to get **PostTitle** of posts at index 0 or use **post.posts.map** to render the array of posts again.

So your code would look something like this -

```
const dashPost = this.state.postData.map(post => (
   <div key={post.UserId}>
       <h1>{post.FirstName}</h1>
        {
          post.posts.map(p => {
             <p>{p.postTitle}</p>
          })
        }
   </div>
));
```